# Printing a certain number of lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to code a program that will print out a certain number of lines from a text file. I think I have the code to open the file and to scan it for how many lines it has. I'm just having trouble printing out the lines. (For example, printing lines 1 through 10 of a file.)

Should I make all the reading of the file into a separate method?

`numLines` is declared earlier from user input.
Also I wanted to make the src open from a command line argument. Unsure if that is implemented correctly.

EDIT COMPLETE CODE IM WORKING WITH

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 256


int numLines = 0;
int linecount = 0;
FILE *src = NULL;
char b[MAX];
char ch;

void GetArgs (int argc, char **argv){
if(argc != 4 || argc != 2) {
    printf("Error not enough arguments to continue \n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);

}// end if argc doenst = 4 or 2

if(argc == 2){
    src = fopen( argv[1], "r:");
    numLines=10;

}// end argc = 2

if(argc == 4){
    if (strcmp (argv[1], "-n") !=0 ){
        numLines = atoi (argv[2]);
        src = fopen (argv[3], "r");
        if ( src == NULL){
            fputs ( "Can't open input file." , stdout);
            exit (-1);
        }
        while (NULL != fgets(ch,MAX, src)){
            linecount++;
            fputs(ch, stdout);
            if (linecount == numLines){
                break;
            }
        }

    }//end of nested if
    else (strcmp (argv[2], "-n") !=0 ){
        numLines = atoi (argv[3]);
        src = fopen (argv[1], "r");
        if ( src == NULL){
            fputs ( "Can't open input file." , stdout);
            exit (-1);
        }
        while (NULL != fgets(ch,MAX, src)){
            linecount++;
            fputs(ch, stdout);
            if (linecount == numLines){
                break;
            }
        }            


    }//end of else
}//end if argc == 4

}// end GetArgs


}// end GetArgs


int main(int argc, char **argv){



GetArgs(argc, argv);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to compile and run it?

Comment: I run into errors. I'm trying to fix all the errors that terminal gives me

Comment: `fgets()` returns a null pointer on EOF.

Comment: You should read up about [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Examples](http://sscce.org/) and provide one.  You should pay attention to your compiler's warnings.  You should be getting complaints about one of `fgets()` or `putc()` — unless you've not included `<stdio.h>`, which would be another bad move.

Comment: To be clear I'm not reading any src file correctly? I do get errors for fputs. 


error: too few arguments to function ‘fputs’
head.c:60: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
FILE * src = NULL;
int linecount = 0;
int numLines = 5;
char ch[MAX];

src = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
if ( src == NULL ) {
    fputs( "Can't open input file.", stdout );
    exit(-1);
}

while(NULL != fgets(ch,MAX,src)) {
    linecount++;
    fputs(ch, stdout);

    if (linecount == numLines) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your code and edit the question showing how my code looks with your code implemented. It still doesnt complile so I'm unsure if it helps. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: #define MAX 1024 and compile it without your code, try to understand an implementation, and than use it in your code

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while ( fgetc(ch,MAX,src) !=EOF )
> ```

You're calling `fgetc` like `fgets`. The `fgetc` takes only one argument: a `FILE *stream`.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. I made the change and that error is gone when I try to compile. thanks again

Comment: V Or, you should fix it the other way around, i.e. use fgetc with the right signature, the rest of your code is based on the assumption that you read one byte at a time.